# Code reuse for unknown field

Tags: c

If I have a sorting algorithm, and I want to sort by some field of a structure. I'm basically looking for the possibility of a parameter (`sortBy` in this case) being able to determine whether fieldOne would be compared, or fieldTwo--without continually checking for the correct field to use.

```
void func(SomeType *arr, int length, int sortBy) {
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < length, i++) {
        if(sortBy == 1) {
            doSomethingTo(arr[i].fieldOne);
        }
        else if(sortBy == 2) {
            doSomethingTo(arr[i].fieldTwo);
        }
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: You could pass in a function pointer to get function so your code would look like for(i = 0; i < length; i++)doSomething(getField(arr[i]));

Comment: you can pass a function like so void func(SomeType *arr, int length, <return type> (*getField)(<argument type>)){...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe what the Standard C [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) does.  It sorts any array of any type, using a comparator function:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
           int (*compar)(const void *v1, const void *v2));
```

The comparator function returns a negative value if `v1` should sort before `v2`, a positive value if it should sort after, and zero if the values are equal under this sorting criterion.  Note that it is necessary to compare two values; it is not sufficient to compare one value with its own navel.

In your example, you are sorting a fixed type, it seems.  You could use `qsort()`, or you can borrow the comparator type idea, and adapt it to your sort:

```
void func(SomeType *arr, int length, int (*comparator)(const SomeType *v1, const SomeType *v2))
{
    ...
    int cmp = comparator(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    ...
}
```

Your comparator might be:

```
static int compare_fieldOne(const SomeType *v1, const SomeType *v2)
{
    if (v1->fieldOne < v2->fieldOne)
        return -1;
    else if (v1->fieldOne > v2->fieldOne)
        return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to do more comparisons, you can add extra pairs of tests after the the `else if` clause, leaving the equality case to the end.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but I'm looking for the possibility of a parameter being able to determine whether `fieldOne` would be compared, or `fieldTwo`. This just seems to compare one set field of `arr`?

Comment: You'd have different comparator functions for the different fields, with different sets of tie-breakers as you see fit.  When you call the sorting function, you'd pass in the comparator that's appropriate.  Or you'd have a 'sort driver function' that decodes the requested field number into the appropriate comparator.  Alternatively, you can arrange to pass an extra parameter to the comparator which indicates the requested comparison, and maybe do tricky things with `offsetof()` to handle the different comparisons.  Given a choice, I'd write a small set of comparator functions.

Comment: I see--I wouldn't have if statements every iteration anymore, but there is still no good way to get the right variable to use without essentially copy-pasting at least some code, like the comparator, right?

Comment: Roughly, yes.  The comparators are where the repetition is; the call sites select which comparator.  The body of the sort just has the function pointer call to the comparator, as illustrated.  (I'd normally write `(*comparator)(&arr[i], &arr[j])` but the extra parentheses and the `*` aren't strictly necessary these days (though they were necessary when I learned C, once upon a very long time ago).

Comment: +1: nice answer. @idlackage: A third parameter specifying an bitmask of which fields to compare, and a fully-implemented comparator that compares fields and adds them to the cumulative result as appropriate based on bits being lit in the mask will probably satisfy the need you're looking for in addition to the callback-mechanics Jonathan provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a solution:

```
void sampleDoSomethingFunction(SomeType *arg) {
}

void func(SomeType *arr, int length, void (*doSomething)(SomeType *arg)) {
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < length, i++) {
        doSomething(&arr[i]);
    }
}
```

then you invoke the func like this:

```
    func(arr,length, sampleDosomethingFunction);
```

Comment: Ummm, this doesn't do what the original function did.  In particular, it never passes `fieldTwo` to `doSomething`.

Comment: @DaleHagglund See the update please. Then you do whatever you like inside dosomething function